# Why dulplicate symbol errors do not occur when linking both libsqlite3.dylib and libsqlcipher.a?

Tags: ios, sqlite, sqlcipher

I'm integrating sqlcipher into an iOS project according to this tutorial: https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/ios-tutorial/
There is a hot tip which says:If libsqlite3.dylib or another SQLite framework is listed in your Link Binary With Libraries list be sure to remove it, or you'll see duplicate symbol errors.
But I tried to add both libsqlite3.tbd(no dylib in xcode 7) and libsqlcipher.a to **Link Binary With Libraries**, the dulplicate symbol error do not occur! Why?
And I notice if I click the `#import <sqlite3.h>` line, xcode show the sqlite3.h file in xcode's lib folder, not the one in sqlcipher.
However, sqlcipher does work, the database is really encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

`libsqlite3.tbd` is just a text file that defines platform architectures supported by the library, target platforms, dylib installation path and exported symbols.  Using a `.tbd` file, you decrease the your bundled application size as the library binary is already included on the platform device so it does not need to be linked into your application image.

`libsqlite3.tbd` looks like this:

```
---
archs:           [ armv7, armv7s, arm64 ]
platform:        ios
install-name:    /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
current-version: 216.4
compatibility-version: 9.0
exports:         
  - archs:           [ armv7, armv7s, arm64 ]
    symbols:         [ __sqlite3_lockstate, __sqlite3_purgeEligiblePagerCacheMemory, 
                       __sqlite3_system_busy_handler, __sqlite_auto_profile, 
                       __sqlite_auto_profile_syslog, __sqlite_auto_trace, 
                       __sqlite_auto_trace_syslog, _sqlite3OsShmHasMultipleLinks, 
                       _sqlite3OsShmRenamedWhileOpen, _sqlite3OsShmWasTruncated, 
                       _sqlite3OsShmWasUnlinkedWhileOpen, _sqlite3VersionNumber, 
                       _sqlite3VersionString, _sqlite3_aggregate_context, 
                       _sqlite3_aggregate_count, _sqlite3_auto_extension, 
                       _sqlite3_backup_finish, _sqlite3_backup_init, _sqlite3_backup_pagecount, 
                       _sqlite3_backup_remaining, _sqlite3_backup_step, 
                       _sqlite3_bind_blob, _sqlite3_bind_blob64, _sqlite3_bind_double, 
                       _sqlite3_bind_int, _sqlite3_bind_int64, _sqlite3_bind_null, 
                       _sqlite3_bind_parameter_count, _sqlite3_bind_parameter_index, 
                       _sqlite3_bind_parameter_name, _sqlite3_bind_text, 
                       _sqlite3_bind_text16, _sqlite3_bind_text64, _sqlite3_bind_value, 
                       _sqlite3_bind_zeroblob, _sqlite3_blob_bytes, _sqlite3_blob_close, 
                       _sqlite3_blob_open, _sqlite3_blob_read, _sqlite3_blob_reopen, 
                       _sqlite3_blob_write, _sqlite3_busy_handler, _sqlite3_busy_timeout, 
                       _sqlite3_cancel_auto_extension, _sqlite3_changes, 
                       _sqlite3_clear_bindings, _sqlite3_close, _sqlite3_close_v2, 
                       _sqlite3_collation_needed, _sqlite3_collation_needed16, 
                       _sqlite3_column_blob, _sqlite3_column_bytes, _sqlite3_column_bytes16, 
                       _sqlite3_column_count, _sqlite3_column_decltype, 
                       _sqlite3_column_decltype16, _sqlite3_column_double, 
                       _sqlite3_column_int, _sqlite3_column_int64, _sqlite3_column_name, 
                       _sqlite3_column_name16, _sqlite3_column_text, _sqlite3_column_text16, 
                       _sqlite3_column_type, _sqlite3_column_value, _sqlite3_commit_hook, 
                       _sqlite3_compileoption_get, _sqlite3_compileoption_used, 
                       _sqlite3_complete, _sqlite3_complete16, _sqlite3_config, 
                       _sqlite3_context_db_handle, _sqlite3_create_collation, 
                       _sqlite3_create_collation16, _sqlite3_create_collation_v2, 
                       _sqlite3_create_function, _sqlite3_create_function16, 
                       _sqlite3_create_function_v2, _sqlite3_create_module, 
                       _sqlite3_create_module_v2, _sqlite3_data_count, 
                       _sqlite3_data_directory, _sqlite3_db_config, _sqlite3_db_filename, 
                       _sqlite3_db_handle, _sqlite3_db_mutex, _sqlite3_db_readonly, 
                       _sqlite3_db_release_memory, _sqlite3_db_status, 
                       _sqlite3_declare_vtab, _sqlite3_enable_shared_cache, 
                       _sqlite3_errcode, _sqlite3_errmsg, _sqlite3_errmsg16, 
                       _sqlite3_errstr, _sqlite3_exec, _sqlite3_expired, 
                       _sqlite3_extended_errcode, _sqlite3_extended_result_codes, 
                       _sqlite3_file_control, _sqlite3_finalize, _sqlite3_free, 
                       _sqlite3_free_table, _sqlite3_get_autocommit, _sqlite3_get_auxdata, 
                       _sqlite3_get_table, _sqlite3_global_recover, _sqlite3_initialize, 
                       _sqlite3_intarray_bind, _sqlite3_intarray_create, 
                       _sqlite3_interrupt, _sqlite3_last_insert_rowid, 
                       _sqlite3_libversion, _sqlite3_libversion_number, 
                       _sqlite3_limit, _sqlite3_log, _sqlite3_malloc, _sqlite3_malloc64, 
                       _sqlite3_memory_alarm, _sqlite3_memory_highwater, 
                       _sqlite3_memory_used, _sqlite3_mprintf, _sqlite3_msize, 
                       _sqlite3_mutex_alloc, _sqlite3_mutex_enter, _sqlite3_mutex_free, 
                       _sqlite3_mutex_leave, _sqlite3_mutex_try, _sqlite3_next_stmt, 
                       _sqlite3_open, _sqlite3_open16, _sqlite3_open_v2, 
                       _sqlite3_os_end, _sqlite3_os_init, _sqlite3_overload_function, 
                       _sqlite3_prepare, _sqlite3_prepare16, _sqlite3_prepare16_v2, 
                       _sqlite3_prepare_v2, _sqlite3_profile, _sqlite3_progress_handler, 
                       _sqlite3_randomness, _sqlite3_realloc, _sqlite3_realloc64, 
                       _sqlite3_release_memory, _sqlite3_reset, _sqlite3_reset_auto_extension, 
                       _sqlite3_result_blob, _sqlite3_result_blob64, _sqlite3_result_double, 
                       _sqlite3_result_error, _sqlite3_result_error16, 
                       _sqlite3_result_error_code, _sqlite3_result_error_nomem, 
                       _sqlite3_result_error_toobig, _sqlite3_result_int, 
                       _sqlite3_result_int64, _sqlite3_result_null, _sqlite3_result_text, 
                       _sqlite3_result_text16, _sqlite3_result_text16be, 
                       _sqlite3_result_text16le, _sqlite3_result_text64, 
                       _sqlite3_result_value, _sqlite3_result_zeroblob, 
                       _sqlite3_rollback_hook, _sqlite3_rtree_geometry_callback, 
                       _sqlite3_rtree_query_callback, _sqlite3_set_authorizer, 
                       _sqlite3_set_auxdata, _sqlite3_shutdown, _sqlite3_sleep, 
                       _sqlite3_snprintf, _sqlite3_soft_heap_limit, _sqlite3_soft_heap_limit64, 
                       _sqlite3_sourceid, _sqlite3_sql, _sqlite3_status, 
                       _sqlite3_status64, _sqlite3_step, _sqlite3_stmt_busy, 
                       _sqlite3_stmt_readonly, _sqlite3_stmt_status, _sqlite3_strglob, 
                       _sqlite3_stricmp, _sqlite3_strnicmp, _sqlite3_table_column_metadata, 
                       _sqlite3_temp_directory, _sqlite3_test_control, 
                       _sqlite3_thread_cleanup, _sqlite3_threadsafe, _sqlite3_total_changes, 
                       _sqlite3_trace, _sqlite3_transfer_bindings, _sqlite3_update_hook, 
                       _sqlite3_uri_boolean, _sqlite3_uri_int64, _sqlite3_uri_parameter, 
                       _sqlite3_user_data, _sqlite3_value_blob, _sqlite3_value_bytes, 
                       _sqlite3_value_bytes16, _sqlite3_value_double, _sqlite3_value_int, 
                       _sqlite3_value_int64, _sqlite3_value_numeric_type, 
                       _sqlite3_value_text, _sqlite3_value_text16, _sqlite3_value_text16be, 
                       _sqlite3_value_text16le, _sqlite3_value_type, _sqlite3_version, 
                       _sqlite3_vfs_find, _sqlite3_vfs_register, _sqlite3_vfs_unregister, 
                       _sqlite3_vmprintf, _sqlite3_vsnprintf, _sqlite3_vtab_config, 
                       _sqlite3_vtab_on_conflict, _sqlite3_wal_autocheckpoint, 
                       _sqlite3_wal_checkpoint, _sqlite3_wal_checkpoint_v2, 
                       _sqlite3_wal_hook ]
...
```

You do not receive a duplicate symbol linker error because you are only including a single binary library, `libsqlcipher.a`.  You need to remove the `libsqlite3.tbd` reference and include `libsqlcipher.a` if you wish to use SQLCipher within your iOS application.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I made another experiment... I download sqlite source code from www.sqlite.org and add sqlite3.h sqlite3.c to the proejct. The duplicate symbol error still doesn't occur...

Comment: Are you certain you are properly linking libsqlcipher.a?

Comment: YES.  libsqlcipher.a is the only one added in Link Binary With Libraries. I check the created sqlite database file with hexdump, it is really encrypted.

Comment: I think there is nothing wrong with sqlcipher, I am just curious about this problem. I also tried other combinations: libsqlite3.0.dylib with sqlite3 source files, wxSQLite3 with sqlite3 source files, libsqlite3.0.dylib with wxSQLite3, the error just does not occur. Many related tutorials also mentioned not to add xxx with yyy together, otherwise the duplicate symbol errors may occur. However, the error just don't occur...

Answer (score 0):

I encounted the same problem, if you do not remove the libsqlite3.0.tbd, the encryption will depend on the ios system, on iOS 13 and later, it will be encrypted using system algorithm, on iOS 12 and earier , the db wont be encrypted.

You did not receive duplicate symbols error, cause the system sqlite is a dynamic library.